# group pandas time series by month across years

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have the following working example where I calculate a normal distribution for every month of this timeseries. What I am looking for is an aggregated distribution that gives back 12 values, so for every month calculated across years. In other words, the subset for January includes the data form January 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, from which the distribution is calculated from.

```
from scipy.stats import norm
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


def some_function(data):
    mu, std = norm.fit(data)
    a = mu * 3
    b = std * 5
    return a, b


rng = pd.date_range('1/1/2011', periods=4*365, freq='D')
ts = pd.Series(np.random.randn(len(rng)), index=rng)
ts.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('M')).apply(some_function).apply(pd.Series).rename(columns={0: 'mu', 1: 'std'})
```

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [year](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.year.html) attribute on the datetime index:

```
In [11]: ts.groupby(ts.index.year).apply(some_function).apply(pd.Series).rename(columns={0: 'mu', 1: 'std'})
Out[11]:
            mu       std
2011  0.110566  4.827900
2012 -0.094430  4.950958
2013 -0.097986  4.965611
2014 -0.078819  4.709263
```